# The skew commutativity of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A,B$ are two $n\times n $ real matrices such that $A^2+B^2=-I_n$, then does $AB+BA=0$ necessarily hold?

Comment: Why do you want to delete this?

Comment: hint: if $n$ is even, then $A^2 = -\frac{1}{2}I$ is possible, you can take $A=B$, and $AB+BA = 2A^2 = -I \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider [the $2\times 2$ real matrices that model the complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers). Can you think of complex numbers $z$ and $w$ such that $z^2+w^2=-1$, but $zw+wz\neq 0$?